# Is checkmarx mark properties named Password as Medium vulnerability regardless to the underlining implementation?

Tags: c#, checkmarx

I'm a little bit confused about why checkmarx mark the below public property **Password** as medium vulnerability of type Heap Inspection.

Any idea why checkmarx mark this line as vulnerability ? 
Any recommendations/improvement ideas for the code below ?

```
SecureString password;

public String Password
{
    get { return SecureStringToString(password); }
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            password = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in value) password.AppendChar(c);
        }
    }
}

String SecureStringToString(SecureString value)
{
    IntPtr valuePtr = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        valuePtr = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(value);
        return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(valuePtr);
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(valuePtr);
    }
}
```

Comment: The moment a `SecureString` is turned into a `String`, it's completely, utterly useless. Learn how `SecureString` works if you want to know the details

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I would appreciate a constructive comment on the question itself.

Comment: It's a constructive comment: you need to learn how `SecureString` works. CheckMarx is completely correct in telling you what you're doing is wrong

Comment: @EbeidSolimanElSayed What do you think `Marshal.PtrToStringUni` does? What do you think happens to the (used to be) secure password text when you call that function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant Checkmarx query does care about the underlying implementation, it precisely looks for password fields/variables of type String. Since you allow your SecureString to be returned as a regular String, as soon as that happens it is once again exposed and becomes vulnerable to "heap inspection" (i.e. the plaintext password is stored in an immutable string variable in memory).

In order to prevent this, you would need to redesign your application so that a plain text password is never needed - it should always be hashed (or rather bcrypt/scrypt/PBKDF2'd) right away.
In the rare cases that a plaintext password is required, store it in a byte array, and then zeroize the array when you are done with it - this doesn't completely solve the issue, but it does allow you to minimize the exposure window, and control the password from being passed around the heap too much.

Answer (score 6):

Because it named password. CheckMarx is a piece of kaka that reacts to words password, index, execute and so on. Avoid them and your code will be secure. (by ChechMarx authors opinion).